# Remove embedded stylesheet for Gutenberg editor on the back end

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

The Gutenberg editor comes with an embedded stylesheet. Here's a snippet from that stylesheet:

```
...

.editor-styles-wrapper {
  font-family: "Noto Serif", serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #191e23;
}

.editor-styles-wrapper p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

...
```

I've enqueued my own editor stylesheet using the following:

```
add_action("enqueue_block_editor_assets", "enqueue_custom_block_editor_assets");
function enqueue_custom_block_editor_assets() {
  wp_enqueue_style("editor-style", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/editor-style.css", null, null);
}
```

Since I have my own editor stylehseet, I'd like to get rid of the default one. A search on this topic yields lots of results for removing default block styling on the *front end*, but I'm referring to the editor styling on the back end. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can do this using the stylesheet api in js. It drives me crazy that WP would add this in right at the end of the page as well, which gives it highest cascading specificity.

Comment: stylesheet api? @MatthewBrent could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet & to a lesser extent https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I drilled down into how it was being injected and found a way to nuke it out via the `block_editor_settings` filter. There is a `styles` key with an array that contains the css. The only iffy thing about this for me is that I'm assuming the shape of the array will always be the same, I should be doing some type of check here.

```php
add_filter( 'block_editor_settings' , 'remove_guten_wrapper_styles' );
public function remove_guten_wrapper_styles( $settings ) {
    unset($settings['styles'][0]);

    return $settings;
}
```

Comment: does not work anymore

Answer (score 1):

My solution was a workaround to automatically override any styles within the `.editor-styles-wrapper`. Using LESS:

**editor-style.css**

```
.editor-styles-wrapper {
    @import "style.less";
}
```

I would still love to disable that embedded stylesheet though, if anyone knows how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Updated working code on 7 June 2023.

It didn't work for me because unset doesn't shift keys in array. This is a working solution.

```
add_filter( 'block_editor_settings' , 'remove_guten_wrapper_styles' );
public function remove_guten_wrapper_styles( $settings ) {
    array_shift( $settings['styles'] );

    return $settings;
}
```